Sufficient conditions to guarantee that weakly convergent sequence also converges strongly
I know that any Hilbert space, $H$, satisfies the Radon-Riesz property:
Any weakly convergent sequence, $x_n \rightharpoonup x$, such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow} \|x_n\| = \|x\|$, is also strongly convergent i.e $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|x_n - x\| = 0$
My question is:
Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a reflexive Banach space, and let ${\cal J}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a functional on $X$. Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1,\dots, \infty}$ be a weakly convergent sequence in $X$, $ x_n \rightharpoonup x$, such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\cal J}(x_n) = {\cal J}(x)$. What are sufficient conditions on ${\cal J}$ to guarantee that any such sequence also converges strongly, $ i.e. \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|x_n - x\| = 0$?
The question is motivated by the theory of regularization in ill-posed Inverse Problems. There a solution, $x$, is obtained as the weak limit of a sequence that also satisfies ${\cal J}(x_n) \rightarrow {\cal J}(x)$, where ${\cal J}$ is an appropriate regularizer. I'm wondering what additional requirements are needed on ${\cal J}$ to guarantee that such sequence also converges strongly.

In most applications the ambient space $X$ is reflexive and by a theorem of Troyanski, each reflexive space admits an equivalent norm that is locally uniformly convex. Hence $X$ has an equivalent norm that has the Radon-Riesz property

I appreciate your comment, but I think it doesn't address my question. You are giving a more general characterization of Banach spaces that have the Radon-Riesz property: all reflexive Banach spaces do, you explain. But my question is about something else:   say I replace $||\cdot||$ with another functional, ${\cal J}$, in the definition of the Radon-Riesz property. Let's call it the ${\cal J}$-Radon-Riesz property. I'm asking: what are sufficient conditions on ${\cal J}$ so that reflexive Banach spaces, say, have the ${\cal J}$-Radon-Riesz property. Does it make sense?

Following the comment above, and in order to make my question more specific, I have restricted it to reflexive Banach spaces

I think I made some progress: let $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, with ${\cal Z} = \phi \circ {\cal J}$ convex, proper. Let  $D^q_{\cal Z}(y;x) = {\cal Z}(y)-{\cal Z}(x)-<q,y-x>$ be its Bregman distance, with $q \in \partial {\cal Z}(x)$. Under the conditions stated in the question $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} D^q_{\cal Z}(x_n;x) = 0$. This suggests looking for ${\cal J}$, and $\phi$ whose Bregman distance at $x$ bounds $||x_n - x||$ from above. This argument proves Hilbert have the Radon-Riesz property,with ${\cal J}(\cdot) = ||\cdot||$, $\phi(t) = \frac{1}{2}t^2$.
